# IntelliSense finished initializing, but an error occurred when attempting to load the document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I newly installed VS Community 2019 -version 16.9.4, then i create a new project for Windows Form App C# but return error on the screen saying;

IntelliSense finished initializing, but an error occurred when attempting to load the document with Error Code: 0x80131500.

It was same error when i retried with both .NET Core 3.1 (Long Term Used) and .NET Core 5.

So also with the NuGet package manager console, as it won't install package

Kindly find the attached screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is a workaround, I unchecked the feature here :
Environment->Preview Features->Load project faster
Otherwise, the Intellisense never end is loading.

Comment: @ziakhan I have done that, still no changes yet not even the ToolBox working.

Comment: Now fixed! Installing .NetFramework Developer Pack from [Microsoft | .Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) solve the issue. Thanks @ziakhan

Comment: Close VS, Open VS, load project. Solved.  With Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.4. and  .NET framework 4.8.03761